# How to recompute an ArrayProxy when any property on an array of models is updated?

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple ArrayProxy (computed) that I'd like to recompute when ANY property on the models inside the source (array) are updated. I need this because the filter_func I use to filter down the array could have any number of dynamic properties on it.

```
    return Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({
      source: undefined,
      content: function () {
        var filter_func = this.get("filter_func");
        return this.get("source").filter(filter_func);
      }.property("source.@each")
    }).create({
      filter_func: filter_func,
      source: this.findAll()
    });
```

Today I'm just using "source.@each" as shown above but this only forces the ArrayProxy to recompute when a new item is added/removed from the source array (not when I change properties on the actual models themselves)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but as items are added or removed, maybe setup an observer on each property of the item being added. You would need to remove the observers on each item being removed from the array.

http://www.matchingnotes.com/ember-array-proxy/observers.html

That whole presentation is a fantastic walkthrough of ArrayProxy.

I'm going to give this a shot and see how it works. I'm very interested in the outcome of this question.

Comment: Interesting - was trying to build a simple filter that would be "key unaware" but ended up making the users of this api push an array of keys (so I know what to change on the ArrayProxy). Let me know what you find :) as I'm still curious to learn more about this observer setup you spoke about

Comment: Here's a rather interesting solution, although it relies on Ember objects and not POJSOs.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110623/observe-change-on-any-attribute-of-an-ember-data

Comment: that resource is excellent! thanks again for the quick reply!