# Observe change on any attribute of an Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is this possible? Something like `.observes('_data')`, but not.

The use case is, I have a `Decays` mixin that has some CPs that say how long its been since a model has been updated. I'd like these CPs to be able to update if any of the model's attrs have changed. `isDirty` also won't work, since my use case uses `store.push` to update the model.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a built-in way to do it, but it wouldn't be very difficult to make one. Just create a base class for all of your models and override the `set` function. Something like this:

```
var BaseModel = DS.Model.extend({
    set: function(keyName, value) {
        var ret = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        var attributes = Ember.get(this.constructor, 'attributes');

        if (attributes[keyName]) {
            this.trigger('attributeChanged');
        }

        return ret;
    }
});
```

Then, you can listen for changes to any attribute like this:

```
model.on('attributeChanged', function() {});
```

I think you can even do something like this in the case of a controller or similar object (although I haven't tested it):

```
Controller.extend(Ember.Evented, {
    modelPropertyChanged: function() {

    }.on('model.attributeChanged')
});
```